# pdftk giving me java exception in create_output() when i try to use fill_form command

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have the following fdf (temp.fdf on the filesystem):

```
%FDF-1.2
1 0 obj
<<
/FDF << /Fields [
<< /T (name) /V (name)>>
<< /T (dob) /V (dob)>>
<< /T (address1) /V (address1)>>
<< /T (address2) /V (address2)>>
<< /T (address3) /V (address3)>>

 ] /F (https://mywebsite.com/demo.pdf) /ID [ <138ff91476c2ae9c9f192e15ac50d7bf>
] >>
>>
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R

>>
%%EOF
```

And I have labels.pdf, which can be downloaded from http://www.terrafrost.com/labels.pdf

I'm trying to use the FDF to fill the PDF with this command:

```
pdftk labels.pdf fill_form temp.fdf output demo.pdf flatten
```

Unfortunately, this yields the following error:

```
Unhandled Java Exception in create_output():
Unhandled Java Exception in main():
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at gnu.gcj.runtime.NameFinder.lookup(libgcj.so.17)
   at java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace(libgcj.so.17)
   at java.lang.Throwable.stackTraceString(libgcj.so.17)
   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(libgcj.so.17)
   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(libgcj.so.17)
```

Any ideas?

I'm running pdftk 2.02. Both temp.fdf and labels.pdf live on the local filesystem in the same directory that I'm running the command in. demo.pdf does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know pdftk is unmaintained and there is not much you can do. I started a fork named [pdftk-java](https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk) a few years back to fix outstanding issues in pdftk, and the latest version as of now (3.2.2) works with your example, so you may want to try it yourself.